# Elastic APM Python - System Metrics don't show process related metrics like memory on Kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-apm

I have a standalone Python application.
The python process is not using any framework. And is a simple standalone python process.
This has been successfully integrated with Elastic APM (+ElasticSearch +Kibana) for capturing telemetries.

**Python version:** 3.7
**elastic-apm python agent:** 5.8.0
**Elastic Search, APM and Kibana Version:** 7.7.1

As mentioned in the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/5.x/configuration.html), I have used the following statements to start capturing metrics from my python process

```
client = elasticapm.Client(service_name="MY_SERVICE",service_node_name="MY_SERVICE_NODE",server_url="=http:///apm-server:8200",recording="true",environment="PROD")
elasticapm.instrument()
```

But on Kibana, I am able to see only the following 3 system metrics (under 2 visualizations):

1. Host's CPU Usage in percentage
2. Process specific CPU Usage in percentage
3. Host's Memory Usage in percentage

As per the [python code](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/blob/5.x/elasticapm/metrics/sets/cpu_linux.py) analysis, as well as per what I have [read](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/5.x/metrics.html). Elastic APM Agent collects other process related metrics like:

1. Memory used by Process
2. Process uptime

## These I am unable to see on the Kibana - APM - Metrics Visualization

**Refer the screenshot**
**[image: Refer the screenshot]**


**Additionally, I expect the Elastic APM Python agent to collect other informations like**:

1. Process's thread level CPU Usage
2. Number of threads in process
3. Garbage collection stats
4. IO Stats

**Which are already available for Elastic APM Java agent.**
**Refer the screenshot**

## [image: Refer the screenshot]


Need help in understanding, whether these process related metrics are available in Kibana - APM or not?

## If available, how to enable the visualization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was cross-posted to discuss.elastic.co, and you can see the answer that was provided there: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-apm-python-system-metrics-dont-show-process-related-metrics-like-memory-on-kibana/240531/2?u=basepi

Comment: Thanks. Got the visualization.